# Set Wordpress user to view my updates

Tags: wordpress, notifications

I am new to Wordpress and I need to set another user (who has a WordPress account) to be notified of any new blog posts I made.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Make an [RSS feed](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-a-rss-feed-to-my-blog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go one of two routes - plugin or manual coding:

**Plugin**

You could use a plugin like "New Post Notification" or "Notify Users E-Mail". (Search the WordPress plugins site.)

**Manual coding**

Sign in to your site and click on "Appearance" then "Editor." Open your theme's functions.php file. Paste the following code at the bottom of the functions file:
function email_members($post_ID) { global $wpdb; $usersarray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_email FROM $wpdb->users;"); $users = implode(",", $usersarray); mail($users, 'A new post has been published'); return $post_ID; }
add_action('publish_post', 'email_members');
Replace the message "A new post has been published" with your custom message and click on "Update File."

(taken from http://smallbusiness.chron.com/notify-users-new-wordpress-blog-31736.html)